# How to configure phpMyAdmin settings on Virtualmin VS creation

Tags: vps, phpmyadmin, webmin

I am having an issue with Virtualmin, I can create virtual servers and create databases fine, although when I access phpMyAdmin, it only shows one database, no matter how many I add.

I found some advice online, which suggests to change the phpMyAdmin config file as shown:

Within `config.inc.php`, Search for

```
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['only_db'] = Array('NAMEOFYOURDB');
```

and change it to :

```
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['only_db'] = Array('%');
```

This works great, although I have to manually go through the files for each virtual server to change this, and I'd like to be able to have virtual servers setup automatically. Is there a way to automate this on virtual server creation? I couldn't find any config files for phpMyAdmin unless it has been installed? Am I just looking for the wrong files?